# How to prevent table row highlight from going away on hover

Tags: html, css

I had everything working fine until I was asked to remove the highlighting hover effect. I managed to make the hover effect transparent but the problem is when I hover over the selected row it of course turns white. I need it to stay the custom color I assigned to the selected row.

```
<table class=" table table-bordred table-striped table-hover">
                    <tr><th>No</th><th>Name</th></tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray" class="pointer" ng-class="{highlight: job.JobNumber===selectedJob.JobNumber}">
                        <td ng-dblclick="editJobModal(job)" ng-click="selectJob(job)">{{job.JobNumber}}</td>
                        <td ng-dblclick="editJobModal(job)" ng-click="selectJob(job)">{{job.JobName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

  .table-striped tbody tr.highlight td { 
  background-color: #428bca;
  color:white;
 }
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #428bca;
  color: black

}
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.not()` selector to specify that the hover should not affect rows with the `.highlight` class:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:not(.highlight):hover td {
  background-color: #428bca;
  color: black
}

.table tbody tr:not(.highlight):hover td,
.table tbody tr:not(.highlight):hover th {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything in your css that will make the background turn white but this might be the culprit. All it is doing is removing the background color of the cells when it's row is highlighted. You can try to remove the following from your css:

```
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I actually need that css to make the hovering transparent. Sorry on the confusion, I just noticed I should have put transparent where I put white.